# Foundation media object - making the main section being high enough for the content

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

I am using zurb foundation v6 in my project, and I have made a media object in my page:

```
         <div class="media-object stack-for-small">
            <div class="media-object-section">
              <img src= "{{ entry.topImage.first().getUrl('square') }}">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section main-section">
              <h4>{{ entry.title }}</h4>
              <p>{{ entry.summary | truncate('words', '50', ' ...', true) }}</p>
              <div class="date">
                <p>{{ entry.dateUpdated | date('j. F Y') }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Since I want the `date` div to be placed at the bottom of the `main-section` I have positioned it with `position: absolute` and `bottom: 1rem`.
The problem is that on the small screens text from `{{ entry.summary }}` goes over the date. I want them to be one from each other on small screens, I have tried with setting the date `padding-top` to `1rem`, and `margin-top` as well, but nothing worked. How can I fix that?

This is the scss file:

```
.results {
  height: 100%;
  background: $gray;

  .media-object {
    background: $white;
  }

  .results-title {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }

  .query {
    padding-left: 1.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .media-object-section {
    width: 300px;

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }

  .main-section {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 1rem;

    .date {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 1rem;

      p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
    }

    h4, p {
      color: $black;
    }

    h4 {
      padding-top: 2rem;
      margin-bottom:1rem;
    }
  }

  @include breakpoint(small only) {
    .main-section {
      padding: 1rem!important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I may be able to help further with a live link...

Answer (score 0):

It may not be much of an answer, but using absolute as you probably know removes the element from the document flow causing your issue. On smaller screens use a media query to re-position that element relative. Like such;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .element {
       position: relative !important;
    }
}
```

This will introduce the element back into the document flow and ensure the surrounding elements flow as per your written rules.

Regards,

-B